# Datagridview's rowindex keeps resetting after filling dataset with a tableadapter

Tags: c#, datagridview, indexing, row

I am using a timer to update my datagridview. The problem is after each update the rowindex goes back to the top left, so basicly the first cell. Is there a way to keep the rowindex the same while filling the dataset? I am using this code to fill the dataset.

```
this.gASFLESSENTableAdapter.Fill(this.dataSet1.GASFLESSEN);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have same row index after filling then

```
int rowindex=datagridview.CurrentRow.Index;
this.gASFLESSENTableAdapter.Fill(this.dataSet1.GASFLESSEN);
datagridview.Rows[rowindex].Selected=true
```

Comment: Oh, nevermind this works but the scrolling index still keeps resetting. Any tips? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ended up solving it myself, but your answer has also helped me. Thank you. I have used the 'FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex' property to set the scrollingindex.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the TableAdapter's `ClearBeforeFill` property to `False` will stop this behaviour. It saves you having to manually get/set the row index and also means that a user in the process of scrolling when `Fill` is called, won't have to deal with a stuck scrollbar.